# PHP - Last login

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to build a 'last user login' script but im not sure how to go about it.

Im my database i have a column 'last login' which is in the format 2011-04-01 15:30:52 for each user, and users that havent logged in yet are 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Could someone help me to get the details of the last user that logged in and disregard the users with 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming MySQL,

select * from users order by last_login desc limit 1;

Answer (score 1):

put `null` instead `0000-00-00 00:00:00` and query

`WHEN last_login IS NOT NULL ORDER BY last_login DESC LIMIT 1`

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($row['last login'] == '0000-00-00 00:00:00') {
    // never logged in
} else {
    echo "Last logged in: " . $row['last login'];
}
```

A lot depends on what do you mean by "build a script..."

Comment: I think you've got "!=" confused with "==" there. :)